# 409 error conflict update, updating pouchDB doc

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a weird conflict with my pouchDB code trying to update a document in my database

code:

```
this.addToExistingUser = function (docId, key, value) {
        usersDatabaseRemote
                .get(docId)
                .then(function (doc) {
                    doc[key] = value;
                    return usersDatabaseRemote.put(doc, docId, doc._rev);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('added field: ' + key + ' to doc ' + docId);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("error from addToExistingUser:");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });

 }
```

where :

```
.factory('usersDatabaseRemote', [
    'pouchDB',
    function (pouchDB) {
        'use strict';

        var usersDatabaseRemote = pouchDB('https://id:pwd@id.cloudant.com/boardl_users');

        return usersDatabaseRemote;
    }
])
```

leads to :

```
{"status":409,"name":"conflict","message":"Document update conflict","error":true,"reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

But as you can see from the code I take the revision number `rev` from the remote document so I don't see why is there a problem with this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you call the function "addToExistingUser" two times in a row ? The conflict might occurs due to async calls on your document.

Comment: Exact ! you're right @AlexisCôté.

Answer (score 1):

credit: @AlexisCôté

I was calling several times the async function that updates the remote doc

```
pouchDBservice.addToExistingUser(userr._id, 'weight',     
pouchDBservice.addToExistingUser(userr._id, 'height', userHeight);
pouchDBservice.addToExistingUser(userr._id, 'technique', userTechnique);
```

and this was messing with the ._rev number.

So now I am doing all the parameters at the same time in an object :

```
pouchDBservice.addObjectToExistingUser(userr._id, objectToAdd);
```

with :

```
this.addObjectToExistingUser = function (docId, obj) {
            usersDatabaseRemote
                .get(docId)
                .then(function (doc) {
                    for (var key in obj) {
                        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        console.log(key, obj[key])
                        doc[key] = obj[key];
                    }
                    return usersDatabaseRemote.put(doc);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('addObjectToExistingUser added object: ' + JSON.stringify(obj) + ' to doc ' + docId);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("error from addObjectToExistingUser:");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        };
```